# How to dislplay data from multiple tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to query a database (classicmodels) where it must satisfy the ff criteria:

1. Show a productname column for each product
2. Show net profit column of each product, tied on year and month
3. Show the date column in YYYY-MM format for each tied product
4. Status of the resulting products should be 'shipped'

The tables I'm drawing these data are listed below:

```
+--------------------+  +----------------+  +----------------+      
| products           |  | orders         |  | payments       |  
+--------------------+  +----------------+  +----------------+  
| productCode        |  | orderNumber    |  | customerNumber |  
| productName        |  | orderDate      |  | checkNumber    |  
| productLine        |  | requiredDate   |  | paymentDate    |  
| productScale       |  | shippedDate    |  | amount         |  
| productVendor      |  | status         |  +----------------+  
| productDescription |  | comments       |                      
| quantityInStock    |  | customerNumber |
| buyPrice           |  +----------------+
| MSRP               | 
+--------------------+

+-----------------+     +-----------------+
| orderdetails    |     | Field           |
+-----------------+     +-----------------+
| orderNumber     |     | productLine     |
| productCode     |     | textDescription |
| quantityOrdered |     | htmlDescription |
| priceEach       |     | image           |
| orderLineNumber |     +-----------------+
+-----------------+
```

1. I'm drawing the date values from the column: **paymentDate** under the table: **payments**
2. I'm drawing the productname values from column: **productName** under the table: **products**
3. I also need to related the **buyPrice**, **quantityOrdered** and **priceEach** in order to get the net profit

This is my current syntax:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(paymentDate, '%Y-%m') AS 'yearmonth', 
productname, 
((priceEach-buyPrice)*(quantityOrdered)) AS 'profit' 
FROM payments
INNER JOIN orders ON orders.customerNumber=payments.customerNumber
INNER JOIN orderdetails ON orderdetails.orderNumber=orders.orderNumber
INNER JOIN products ON products.productCode=orderdetails.productCode
WHERE status='Shipped'
ORDER BY 'productname' ASC;
```

But the output goes like this:

[image: this.]

How will I write my SQL query so that the output will be this?

[image: this one?]

Comment: And? what is the question? What is wrong with your query?

Comment: Hi, sorry I've updated the post now. my problem is that I cannot replicate the result on the 2nd picture. I don't know if there is a missing or wrong assignment of functions in my syntax. I was wondering is someone can correct and help me.

Comment: Only filal ordering is wrong? *But the output goes like this:* Shown output contradicts with query text (its ORDER BY clause). Check if it is your client software issue (hidden ordering by 1st column maybe?)...

Answer (score 0):

```
 select DATE_FORMAT(p.paymentDate,'%Y-%m') as yearMonth, pr.productname, ((o.priceEach- 
 pr.buyPrice)*(o.quantityOrdered)) AS 'profit' from 

 Payments p
 INNER JOIN orders o ON p.customerNumber=o.customerNumber and o.status='Shipped'
 INNER JOIN orderdetails od ON o.orderNumber=od.orderNumber
 INNER JOIN products pr ON od.productCode=pr.productCode ORDER BY pr.productname ASC;
```

once give a try with this and let me know if any issues. Thank you

Comment: I'll give this one a try. Will update you. Thank you.

Comment: The syntax worked! It's wonderful. Thanks! I'm just wondering now why it the order was not the same as the 2nd picture.

Comment: @Mark Once interchange first and third INNER JOINS and check.

Comment: I got an update and tried your recommendation. It got an error when I interchanged the 1st and 3rd inner joins